# Show parameter value in icon view in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to show the value of a parameter in the icon view with `textString = "%a"` as shown in the annotation below.

```
model temp

 parameter Integer a = 2;

equation

  annotation(
    Icon(graphics = {
      Rectangle(origin = {-6, 30}, extent = {{-50, 34}, {50, -34}}), 
      Text(origin = {-14, 37}, extent = {{-24, 11}, {24, -11}}, textString = "%a")}));
end temp;
```

However in the iconview of OpenModelica, i just see %a instead of 2. This works in Wolfram SystemModeller, so is this a bug or a limitation in OpenModelica or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

In the icon view OpenModelica displays the text you entered. It is meant to design the icon. As a developer you see that the value will not always be 2, but it depends on a parameter.

[image: Icon View]

As soon as you instantiate the model and switch to the diagram view, the parameter value is shown:

[image: Example]